# Gitignoring hidden and normal matches

Tags: gitignore

I can gitignore all files beginning with a hash with `\#*` and all hidden files beginning with (a dot and) a hash with `.\#*`.  But can I ignore both with one pattern?

Answer (score 1):

This is closer, as I detail in "[What pattern does .gitignore follow?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34960504/6309):

```
 shopt -s dotglob
```

Then edit your `.gitignore` with:

```
 *.\#*
```

But that would probably not ignore a `#foo` (ie, without `.#*` extension), only `xxx.#yyy`.

So two patterns remain the safest setting.