# Difference between *.zip and .zip in .gitignore (zip is a example)

Tags: git, gitignore

In `.gitignore` I specified `.zip` and it didn't work.
But when I did `*.zip` it filtered my files to be commited.

What's the difference between these two?

Comment: It would make it clearer if you [edit] to show an example of the files: which files need to get ignored but "didn't work" and which files were successfully ignored after `*.zip`. Do you have files named example `foo.zip`, `bar.zip`, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What pattern does .gitignore follow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34901807/what-pattern-does-gitignore-follow)

Comment: @GinoMempin yes exactly I have foo.zip, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.gitignore` is looking for file names or glob patterns, not extensions.

Without the wildcard, `.zip` in your `.gitignore` is only matching a literal file called `.zip`, which is unlikely to exist, but if you were to create it (say by calling `touch .zip` you'd find that `git` correctly ignores it.